# Как включить, отключить устройство на C++ на win х64?

Tags: c++

Как включить, отключить устройство на C++ на win х64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве возможно альтернативы можно через командную строку обращаться к утилите [devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) и, используя ее возможности, включать либо выключать устройство. Для 64-битной системы есть подходящая версия.

Comment: я так и хотел. у меня батник есть как раз с ним. теперь хочу на С++ реализовать, но не могу devcon запустить при компиляции. cmd открыл, а вот команду не могу применить.

Comment: system(имя-батника-с-devcon);

Comment: А напрямую? не через батник пример команды devcon enable id устройства

Comment: Так же. Что-то вроде

    char cmd[1000]; 
    sprintf(cmd,"devcon enable id %d",devno);
    system(cmd);

Ваша цель сформировать в `cmd` такую же строку, что Вы из окошка CMD вводите и вызвать с ней system().

Comment: system("cmd.exe /k devcon disable PCI\\VEN_1002*");
вот так получилось, но остается висеть смд окно. как убрать?

Comment: @zra123, ну Вы сами-то help cmd, например почитайте. 

Кстати, почему вдруг без cmd.exe devcon не запускается? Попробуйте задать полный путь к нему (может с буквой устройства).

Answer (score 5):

Никак. На C++ - никак. Необходимо использовать сторонние библиотеки. Прошу уточнить какие именно Вы готовы использовать, тогда можно будет дать более развернутый ответ.

Например, можно использовать средства [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394572.aspx) или использовать специальные вызовы [Win32API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363234.aspx)

И еще обязательно поглядите [эту уже написанную программу с исходными кодами](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14469/Simple-Device-Manager).

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <device>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    device *dev = new device();
    dev->on();
    dev->off();
    delete dev;
    return 0;

}
```

Так попробуйте.

Comment: Это такой толстый троллинг?

Comment: Какой вопрос, такой ответ. Извините, не удержался.

Comment: Говорят, если задать вопрос на американском форуме, дадут ответ на десяти страницах, на немецком - на двадцати, на русском - на сорока объяснят, какой ты м... дурак.

Answer (score 2):

С++ - это, если вы не знали, язык не только для Windows:

```
  Как включить, отключить устройство на C++ на win х64?
```

Код на C++ может быть запущен на самых разных устройствах: начиная с наручных часов и заканчивая роботами. Исходя из этого можно сделать вывод, что нативных средств для аппаратного взаимодейтсвия с Windows 64bit в ядро языка не встроено, иначе бы, если бы для каждого устройства( или совокупности устройств ) в ядро встраивали бы нативные стредства взаимодействия, то ядро бы раздулось до небывалых размеров! Это абсурд. Для взаимодействия с Windows, например, используется WinApi( в вашем случае, это взаимодействие с мышью, монитором, клавиатурой и т.д ).

Answer (score 1):

Чуть погуглил.

Может быть [DeleteVolumeMountPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363927.aspx) это то, что Вы ищете (для отключения)?